# JSON parse loop skip if dictionary value not present

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm using the OpenStreetMap API to extract some data about a particular area using the code below:

```
import requests
import json

overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
overpass_query = """
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"="DE"][admin_level=2];
(node["amenity"="place_of_worship"](area);
 way["amenity"="place_of_worship"](area);
 rel["amenity"="place_of_worship"](area);
);
out center;
"""
response = requests.get(overpass_url, 
                        params={'data': overpass_query})
data = response.json()
```

I then try to print out all the 'names' from the above using the following code:

```
for tags in data['elements']:
    print(tags['tags']['name'])
```

This works fine for the first 12 or so results, but hits an issue when it comes across a result without a 'name' value within the 'tags' dictionary:

```
Epiphanias Kirche
Kirche St. Bilhildis
Kleine Kreuzkirche
Marienkapelle
Kath. Kirche Heilige Familie
St. Cyriakus
Friedhofskapelle
Ev. Hoffnungsgemeinde / Philippuszentrum
Petrikirche
Sankt Paulus
Kapelle Höver
Pfarrkirche St. Laurentius

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-5758361aa6f2> in <module>()
      1 for tags in data['elements']:
----> 2     print(tags['tags']['name'])
      3 
      4 #error occurs because not all have name tags

KeyError: 'name'
```

Is there a way I could skip any missing 'name' values and just keep on parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `dict.get`

**Ex:**

```
for tags in data['elements']:
    print(tags['tags'].get('name'))
```

you can also set a default value. Ex: `print(tags['tags'].get('name', "EMPTY"))`